# Python function keeps returning 0

Tags: python, python-2.7

So i'm running python 2.7 and I've been trying to get this code to display the corresponding number (chamod) with the input (cha), but it keeps returning 0. How do I get it to get the corresponding output? It should be printing out 2.

```
def charismamod(cha):
    chamod = 0
    if cha == 1:
        chamod = -5
    elif cha == 2 | cha == 3:
        chamod = -4
    elif cha == 4 | cha == 5:
        chamod = -3
    elif cha == 6 | cha == 7:
        chamod = -2
    elif cha == 8 | cha == 9:
        chamod = -1
    elif cha == 10 | cha == 11:
        chamod = 0
    elif cha == 12 | cha == 13:
        chamod = 1
    elif cha == 14 | cha == 15:
        chamod = 2
    elif cha == 16 | cha == 17:
        chamod = 3
    elif cha == 18 | cha == 19:
        chamod = 4
    elif cha == 20:
        chamod = 5
    return chamod
def barbarian():
    cha = 14
    bchamod = charismamod(cha)
    print bchamod
barbarian()
```

Comment: @cdonts Thank you! || showed up as invalid syntax. What does | do, then?

Comment: `|` is the *bitwise or*. See [BitwiseOperators](https://wiki.python.org/moin/BitwiseOperators).

Comment: Isn't this just `(cha - 10) // 2`?

Answer (score 2):

You have to use `or` instead of `|` :

```
def charismamod(cha):
    chamod = 0
    if cha == 1:
        chamod = -5
    elif cha == 2 or cha == 3:
        chamod = -4
    elif cha == 4 or cha == 5:
        chamod = -3
    elif cha == 6 or cha == 7:
        chamod = -2
    elif cha == 8 or cha == 9:
        chamod = -1
    elif cha == 10 or cha == 11:
        chamod = 0
    elif cha == 12 or cha == 13:
        chamod = 1
    elif cha == 14 or cha == 15:
        chamod = 2
    elif cha == 16 or cha == 17:
        chamod = 3
    elif cha == 18 or cha == 19:
        chamod = 4
    elif cha == 20:
        chamod = 5
    return chamod
def barbarian():
    cha = 14
    bchamod = charismamod(cha)
    print bchamod
barbarian()
```

`|` is a bitwise operator. You have to use `or` or `||`.

> x | y
>
> Does a "bitwise or". Each bit of the output is 0 if the corresponding
>   bit of x AND of y is 0, otherwise it's 1.

[BitwiseOperators](https://wiki.python.org/moin/BitwiseOperators)

Answer (score 2):

As already other people mentioned you should use `or` instead of `|`. However what you should really do is to use a proper dictionary instead of the if-ology:

```
mapping = {
    1: -5,
    2: -4,
    3: -4,
    4: -3,
    5: -3,
    6: -2,
    7: -2,
    8: -1,
    9: -1,
    10: 0,
    11: 0,
    12: 1,
    13: 1,
    14: 2,
    15: 2,
    16: 3,
    17: 3,
    18: 4,
    19: 4,
    20: 5,
}

def charismamod(cha):
    return mapping.get(cha, 0)
```

which makes it easier to read and change in future.

You could also play around with math:

```
def charismamod(cha):
    return (cha / 2) - 5
```

which gives you the most compact and easy to understand function (with a bit different functionality since it works differently for anything outside of `1, ..., 20` set).

Comment: If needed you could why extend the latter function with some range tests to make it behave like the other

Answer (score 0):

Use `or`.

What you do is the 'bitwise or' which works in a different way to what you want to do.
You can read a quick summary here: http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/bitwise_operators_example.htm